# NSDate issue, the date is the day before then it should be

Tags: ios, ios4, nsdate

I want to implement method, that will count the number of days in month. Everything is fine except my date is the day before then it should be. In the following example date is "2012-09-14 21:00:00 +0000" and should be 2012-09-15 21:00:00 +0000 Will appreciate for your help. My code is:

```
NSDictionary *curDay = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"9",@"mounthNumber",@"15",@"day",@"2012",@"year", nil];
NSDateComponents *selectedMounth = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:
NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[calendar setTimeZone: timezone];
[selectedMounth setYear:[[curDay objectForKey:@"year"] integerValue]];
[selectedMounth setMonth:[[curDay objectForKey:@"mounthNumber"] integerValue]];
[selectedMounth setDay:[[curDay objectForKey:@"day"] integerValue]];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:selectedMounth];
```

Comment: And if you just do [selectedMounth setDay:15]; - does it make the correct date?

Comment: No.. Actually that was the first thing I tried while debugging this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your timeZone seems to be something like GMT-3 (or GMT+3, I never remember). Instead of the `systemTimeZone` use the GMT one:`[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];` and it solves your problem.

Comment: Note the +0000 in his date printouts => GMT zone.

Comment: Sorry @SVD, but the fact of using the GMT timeZone explicitly corrects this problem. It's unfair to downgrade my answer without testing the solution I give.

Comment: Zaphod's answer is correct. The date is being set to midnight system time zone; the dump prints it in GMT. Thus, the offset. This is basic NSDate behaviour.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. Although it would appear the problem is not with the actual generation of the date, but rather with the printout - so it may be unnecessary to adjust the Calendar's time zone in any way.